# Azure Multi Factor Authentication for a custom ASP.Net web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have created an ASP.Net web app and hosted it on MS Azure where users sign in and are able to log into the system. I am not using Azure AD or on-premise AD but using Azure SQL database. Users are registering on the web app as normal users. I would like to know if there is a way to integrate Azure Multi Factor Authentication with my custom written app.

Any clarifications required, please ask.

Comment: Please let me know the reason of downvote..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question it sounds like you're using some kind of ASP.NET identity feature which uses a SQL database as the backend.  If so, then you might want to take a look at this article:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AddingTwoFactorAuthenticationToAnASPNETApplication.aspx

It shows in detail how to configure multi-factor authentication for an ASP.NET application using ASP.NET Identity 2.0.  It should work regardless of whether you're hosting on premise or in Azure.

If you're asking how to integrate Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication into your existing ASP.NET identity subsystem, then I fear that may not be possible unless you take a dependency on Azure AD as your identity subsystem.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I am using normal registration (so its not even ASP.Net Identity) because of the architecture. From your answer and link I understand that it's not possible to integrate MFA without using Azure AD. I have integrated 2 factor authentication using a new table and sending SMS codes via SMS API.

Comment: Marking this as answer as it decides that what I am looking for is not achievable at this point of time.